# Why can Xcode build & run on the device but not Profile on device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning

Build & run works fine on my iPhone 5 with Xcode 4.5.2.

But when I try to Profile on the device I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'CG82BAAB-492F-5973-322F-F185257EA26B' 
can't be found
```

I tried to unset and re-set the developer team provisioning profile in the Debug code signing section of the build settings but this didn't solve the issue.

This is a project I dragged over to my new Mountain Lion mac from an old Snow Leopard Mac. It's a old iPhone 4 project which I am trying to migrate to iPhone 5.

Comment: In code build settings -> code signing entity did you select the correct profile for both debug and release? Also check the "Any iOS SDK" part. Try setting it again and then run.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a project I dragged over to my new Mountain Lion mac from an old Snow Leopard Mac. It's a old iPhone 4 project which I am trying to migrate to iPhone 5.

It is likely that you did not transfer your developer certificates and profiles from the old computer. Check in Xcode organizer what you have installed there... also, you can sync from Xcode with your developer account, so you can avoid manually copying the profiles over, but you need to install the developer certificates at least...